# spring boot guide missing autoconfigure

Tags: spring-boot, maven-plugin

I am just going through the Spring Boot guide Tutorial:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

In the Step while adding the Unittests seems broken.
The class misses some Imports:

`import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
 import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;`

Of course I can search and add the maven packages manually, but I want to know if this package should be enough? If though, what could be wrong in my code?

The guide says, this is enough:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Thanks for any infos!

Comment: Click on the download the code at the top right of the tutorial and use that code instead.

Comment: Thy! Ill try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... bottom line it was a stupid typo...

```
in pom.xml 
in <parent> tag
I used the <version>1.2.3 ....

It works with <version>1.5.3 ....
```

Sry for the inconvienece.